# In Database there are 2 events but when click on Submit it shows 4 events(actually it doubles it up ) ? How to solve this issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-redux

```
  const allEvents = async () => {
```

In Database there are 2 events but when click on Submit it shows 4 events(actually it doubles it up ) ? How to solve this issue
But as soon as i click submit it just doubles up the events in an array if there 2 events in database ,it shows 4 events means its duplicating the values

Answer (score 1):

After your submit handler adds a document to the database it calls `allEvents()`, which then reloads all documents from the database and adds them to existing contents of `array`.

You'll want to clear the `array` before adding the documents from the database to it:

```
const allEvents = async () => {
    array = [] // 
    ...
}
```

Comment: its not working

Comment: That doesn't give me a lot to go on Rishi. Did the explanation I gave in my answer make sense? Does it then also make sense why the change I showed would be needed? --- If you still have problems, I recommend setting a breakpoint in the async handler, running the code in a debugger, and stepping through it line by line, checking the value of each variable.